# Bad file descriptor when trying to connect socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to run this code in Python:

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.32'
PORT = 29299

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
socket.send("Hello World".encode())
```

and before the socket is even connect I get the error **OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor**, what may be the problem? I'm using macOS 12.0.1 with firewall off (for some reason the same code runs well on a PC).

The full error traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Client.py", line 9, in <module>
    my_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Don't name your variable `socket`, as this conflicts with the imported package name.

Comment: @JohnGordon done, anyway, changing the var name didn't help..

Comment: In your code sample `connect()` is on line 6, but the error message says line 9.  Is there any important code you haven't shown?

Comment: I have ```#!/usr/bin/env python3``` and then a line break in the beginning @JohnGordon

Comment: What's your execution environment?  In some environments, once you `import socket` and then clobber the `socket` name with `socket = socket.socket(...)`, it will stay wrong until you restart that IDE.  Just changing the name after-the-fact may still leave `socket` incorrect.

Comment: Also, running the exact code as posted (even with the name conflict) does not give the error message given.  It just times out trying to connect to a non-existent server.  Make  sure to post a [mcve] that can be run as posted and produce the error.

Comment: I just tried to run it through the terminal and it works fine! I use CodeRunner editor which I really like, how can I still make it work? @MarkTolonen